# Loading values into a Kendo MVC Multiselect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am trying to preload my multiselect with values. I cannot seem to find an example of this that uses Ajax as the datasource. Here is my view code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model => model.CompanyIds)
    .Name("CompanyIds")
    .AutoClose(false)
    .AutoBind(false)
    .Placeholder("Select companies...")
    .DataTextField("CompanyName")
    .DataValueField("CompanyId")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetAvailableCompanies", "Admin");
        }).ServerFiltering(true);
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control" })
)
```

And here is my controller code:

```
    public ActionResult Portals()
    {
        var portals = new Portals();
        portals.GetBySqlStatement("SELECT * FROM Portal WHERE IsDeleted = 0");
        var adminPortals = portals.Select(portal => new Infrastructure.ViewModels.AdminPortal
        {
            PortalName = portal.PortalName,
            PortalId = portal.PortalId,
            CompanyIds = new List<int> { 1 }
        }).ToList();

        return View(adminPortals);
    }
```

Here is my `GetAvailableCompanies` method:

```
public virtual JsonResult GetAvailableCompanies([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var companies = new Companys();

    companies.GetBySqlStatement("SELECT * FROM Company WHERE IsDeleted=0 ORDER BY CompanyName");

    return Json(companies, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I tried adding `.Value(new List<int> {1})` to the end of the multiselect, but it doesn't select it. I think the issue is that, because its Ajax, the value doesn't "yet exist" in the multiselect. Does anyone know the proper way to handle this? I tried looking for an event on the multiselect that executes after databinding, also with no luck.

**EDIT**

My view is using this model:

```
@model AdminPortal
```

and here is the class definition:

```
public class AdminPortal
{
    public int PortalId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Portal Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Portal Name is required")]
    public string PortalName { get; set; }

    public List<int> CompanyIds { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your `MultiSelectFor()` has `read.Action("GetAvailableCompanies", "Admin");`  i.e calling the `GetAvailableCompanies()` method of `AdminController` - which you have not shown.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I did not think it was relevant to the issue. But I edited my question and added the code.

Comment: I would suggest that unless `Company` contains only 2 properties (`CompanyId` and `CompanyName`) that you return a collection of anonymous object containing only those 2 properties to avoid sending unnecessary data across the wire.

Comment: But something looks odd here - is the view your referring to returned by the `Portals()` method? - it returns a collection so your model is `@model List<Portal>` which means `MultiSelectFor(m=> m.CompanyIds)` would not work. Is the view you have shown a custom `EditorTemplate`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Sorry, I didn't show that. Look at my edit. I provided the class and the `@model` definition. Also, you are right. I'm going to create a class that contains only `CompanyId` and `CompanyName`. For now, I'm just using this to test with.

Comment: And your sure your `GetAvailableCompanies` does return a Company that has `CompanyId = 1`? (I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code - although you don't really need `.Name("CompanyIds")` since that's already added by the helper)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Absolutely 100% sure. Once the multiselect is rendered, I can inspect the element in Chrome and clearly see it. Like I said, I think the issue is that its trying to select "1" before the ajax has loaded and populated the multiselect. Is this possible?

Comment: Its been a long time since I tested out the control, but I'm fairly sure that was not a problem. Does `.AutoBind(true)` make any difference?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I just tried that. That fixed my issue! It now works as expected. Thats weird because several of Telerik's threads, including [this one](http://www.telerik.com/forums/multiselect-ajax-and-displaying-selected-values) have `AutoBind` set to `false`. At any rate, thanks for the help. If you make your suggestion into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
.AutoBind(false)
```

to

```
.AutoBind(true)
```

Side note: The `.Name("CompanyIds")` option is not required since your using and expression (`.MultiSelectFor(m => m.CompanyIds)`) which will add the `name="CompanyIds"` attribute anyway.